# AWS load balancer just loops back to login page

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

So I have two EC2 instances hosting a tomcat/spring application. If I go to those instances separately I have no problem logging in and using the app. But when I set up a AWS load balancer in front of those apps when I try and log in now it just redirects me back to the login page after I hit submit. The strange thing is I see the soap request in my logs. I thought it might have something to do with it being sticky/non-sticky but i'm at a loss. Is there some functionality that I might be missing?

Comment: "I thought it might have something to do with it being sticky/non-sticky but i'm at a loss" That sounds like the first thing to check. Why are you at a loss? Did you try enabling sticky sessions in the load balancer? What if you remove one of the instances from the load balancer so that the LB only has one target, does it work then?

Comment: @MarkB to answer your question yes if my load balancer only points to one node I have no problem longing in. It's when I have my LB pointing to the two different instances. I have played with the sticky sessions. But I thought the LB are sticky by default? Maybe I got that backwards.

Comment: Load balancers are not sticky by default. You need to enable sticky load balancer sessions. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @MarkB you are correct... this solved my problem. But I can't use sticky sessions. But that's a different problem.. I think it's my memcahce/ElastiCachethat is donking now.

Comment: OK I'll bite, why can't you use sticky sessions?

Comment: @MarkB From my understanding it's the best way to design the app. For auto scaling and working with stateless apps. Or if my node dies and the user has to go back to that app.

Comment: So you prefer not to use sticky sessions, not that you "can't".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is with sessions.  You can fix this short-term with sticky sessions, but this will not work well in an autoscaled environment - nodes that are added will not take traffic from existing users, and nodes that are removed will terminate the associated sessions.

By default, it seems like a lot of tomcat installations use multi-cast for session replication.  This does not work in AWS, so you need an alternative solution.

Memcached or redis is probably your best bet.  You need to decide what approach works best.  A elasticache memcached node will work, but becomes a single point of failure.  Redis can be configured for failover in a cluster, but you will need to use the AWS client for this to work.

For either case, you will need to install the appropriate client and configure it to talk to the elasticache node or cluster.

A bonus of either of these is that you can also use it for caching.